# How to add parameter to URL when passing ids as arguments to a page?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with an action *Pass ids as arguments to a page* where I need to add to the link. There is a parameter which I receive in the URL. I can print the parameter in the view, but I am not able to pass it as a token. It is not parsed.

Any ideas?

---

Basically I need to duplicate a node and assign to it a dynamic list of properties (other nodes). I created a view and added a VBO field. User select the ids and they get passed to my URL for elaboration. So far so good. My problem is that I need to pass, in addition to the ids, another field from the view. I tried to specify it in the URL `/admin/myurl/[my_field]`, but it doesn't parse the token.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I follow your question.  Perhaps you could expand slightly or add some more detail?

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay. Sure.

I need to duplicate a node and assign to it a dynamic list of properties (other nodes).

I created a view and added a vbo field. User select the ids and they get passed to my url for elaboration. So far so good.

My problem is that I need to pass, in addition to the ids, another field from the view. I tried to specify it in the URL /admin/myurl/[my_field] but it doesn't parse the token.

As I said, I am new to Drupal and might be using a twisted way to do something that can be easily done in another way.

Comment: I suggest writing a custom VBO action (you can use the "Pass ids" one as the starting point)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the workaround by implementing token support in `hook_drupal_goto_alter`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_drupal_goto_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_drupal_goto_alter(&$path, &$options, &$http_response_code) {
  if (module_exists('token') && user_access('administer nodes') && strpos($path, '[') !== FALSE) {
    // If token is found in path, replace it.
    // This feature is only available for admins for safety reasons.
    $path = token_replace($path);
  }
}
```

This will work for VBO select action, so you can use the path like: `/some/path/[current-page:arg:4]/csv` to pass the 4th parameter from the URL into another view.

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion from this [post](https://www.drupal.org/node/2143209), you should write a custom action using `hook_action_info` similar as *Pass ids as arguments* VBO action, so consider duplicating it as a starting point.

See also the following feature request: [Token support in "Pass ids as arguments to a page" URL field](https://www.drupal.org/node/2270983).